# Why is this app.locals function in a button not working on my EJS template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have this script `agents.js` as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express(); // is it wise to call express like this twice?

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var query = "role=agent";
  get('employees').then(function(data) {
    res.render("agents", {
        rows: result,
        user: req.user
    });          
  }, function(error) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
});        

/// how can I expose this function to the application properly?
app.locals.add2Users = function(item) {
  console.log("ADDING SOMEONE");

  api.create(item, 'employees').then(function(data) {
    console.log("Nice");
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Error");
  });
};

module.exports = router;
```

And a simple template `agents.ejs`

```
<% for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>                                  
        <td>
            <%= rows[i].name %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= rows[i].email %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <% if (rows[i].toAdd) { %>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-circle btn-lg m-r-5" onClick="add2Users(rows[i])">
                    <i class="ti-magnet"></i>
                </button>
            <% } %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

The goal is to create a user on some back end database when the button on the template is clicked, by calling the `add2Users` function. I read that you can expose a function on an EJS template by adding it to `app.locals`, however I am getting the error `add2Users is not defined`. What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to expose a script function on an EJS template without going against best practices so to speak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `app.locals`, I ended up creating an endpoint `/addUser/{param}` and calling the endpoint from the client on click of the button.